# Run a program built with gcc8 on a producing environment without gcc8

Tags: gcc, centos, yum, libstdc++, devtoolset

My developing/producing environments are all CentOS-7.7.
In order to compile my program with gcc-8.3.0, I have installed "devtoolset-8" on my developing env, but it can not be used in the way same as gcc-4.8.5 that was shipped with CentOS7 oringinally.
Every time I need to compile a program, I must use "scl enable devtoolset-8 -- bash" to switch to gcc8 instead of gcc4.8.5.

When the program was deploying onto the producing-env, there is no gcc8, nor libstdc++.so.6.0.25, so it can not run.
I guess libstdc++.so.6.0.25 should be released with gcc8? I can neither install "devtoolset-8" on the producing-env, nor build gcc8 from source on the producing env.
The version of libstdc++ that can be installed from the official yum repo of CentOS, is libstdc++.so.6.0.19, hence my programs can not be loaded at the producing-env.
How to let such programs to run?

Thanks!
Pls forgive my Ugly English.

Comment: You have to either (1) link with libstdc++ statically or (2) copy the shared version of libstdc++ from the compilation machine to the target machine *somehow*. It doesn't need to be a full blown install, but you will have to tell your executable where (on the target machine) the library resides.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to not have to copy or ship a separate `libstdc++.so` but rather link statically (as suggested in a comment) against the `C++` runtime, one can link `C++` programs with `-static-libstdc++` (also specifying `-static-libgcc` will also make sure that the program does not depend on a recent enough version of libgcc_s.so on the system - although that should rarely be a problem).

There can also be the issue of the target system having a version of `glibc` that is too old (relative to the build system). In that case, one could anyhow compile `gcc` of no matter how recent of a version on the older system, so that the resulting `C++` executables as well as `libstdc++` are linked against the older `glibc`. Linking `C++` programs with `-static-libstdc++` will again help to not depend on the program having to be able to find `libstdc++.so` at run-time.

Finally, the `C++` program could also be linked with `-static` not depending on any dynamic libraries at all.